# UITableView scroll outside of frame

Tags: swift, uitableview, scroll

I have a UITableView with a fixed width. The table is centered in its container so that there are white margins both on the left and the right.

Is it possible to scroll the table also with the finger on the white space?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: after matt suggestion i've tried with a pan gesture recognizer
unfortunately it's not working so smooth, there is no bounce at all

```
@IBAction func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self.view)
    self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.tableView.contentOffset.y - translation.y), animated: true)
}
```

Comment: You could put a gesture recognizer on the white space and respond to a pan gesture by scrolling the table.

Comment: ok, i've put a pan gesture recognizer on the container, and with the handlePan i'm reading the translation, how can I scroll the table to that y?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619400-setcontentoffset ?

Comment: Why don't you design your cell that way ? and have full width tableview ?

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya it could be a solution

Comment: @matt it's not working so good, I've edited the original answer with the code i've implemented so fare

Comment: @Janky It is better to do that , better than  handling  gestures

Comment: that would require me a lot of work on the cells i've already developed, so if there's any workaround... but I've tried on one cell and for the moment is the only solution that is working good!

Answer (score 0):

You can put tableview in a scrollview and set Clip to Bounds to false. Shared storyboard sample below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="14109" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="BYZ-38-t0r">
    <device id="retina5_5" orientation="portrait">
        <adaptation id="fullscreen"/>
    </device>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="14088"/>
        <capability name="Constraints to layout margins" minToolsVersion="6.0"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="tne-QT-ifu">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="BYZ-38-t0r" customClass="ViewController" customModule="OptionalTest" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="8bC-Xf-vdC">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="414" height="736"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" fixedFrame="YES" text="Label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="zrT-93-180">
                                <rect key="frame" x="65" y="149" width="221" height="134"/>
                                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                            <scrollView multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="TPs-fa-Cha">
                                <rect key="frame" x="20" y="20" width="374" height="429"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="LQo-x0-VDn">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="414" height="429"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="8PI-hl-lry">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="-20" y="0.0" width="414" height="429"/>
                                                <subviews>
                                                    <tableView clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" alwaysBounceVertical="YES" dataMode="prototypes" style="plain" separatorStyle="default" rowHeight="-1" estimatedRowHeight="-1" sectionHeaderHeight="28" sectionFooterHeight="28" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="2v6-FK-vyt">
                                                        <rect key="frame" x="30" y="20" width="354" height="389"/>
                                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.0" green="0.47843137250000001" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                        <prototypes>
                                                            <tableViewCell clipsSubviews="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" id="gZa-kH-87J">
                                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="28" width="354" height="44"/>
                                                                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                                                <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins="YES" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" tableViewCell="gZa-kH-87J" id="Oid-Rc-aH5">
                                                                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="354" height="43.666666666666664"/>
                                                                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                                                    <subviews>
                                                                        <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Test" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="dJP-b6-Ftm">
                                                                            <rect key="frame" x="20" y="11" width="500" height="22"/>
                                                                            <constraints>
                                                                                <constraint firstAttribute="height" priority="750" constant="50" id="vcL-NN-bXq"/>
                                                                            </constraints>
                                                                            <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                                            <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                                            <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                                        </label>
                                                                    </subviews>
                                                                    <constraints>
                                                                        <constraint firstAttribute="bottomMargin" secondItem="dJP-b6-Ftm" secondAttribute="bottom" id="DgB-3a-RR8"/>
                                                                        <constraint firstItem="dJP-b6-Ftm" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="Oid-Rc-aH5" secondAttribute="leadingMargin" id="Hli-JL-2Qr"/>
                                                                        <constraint firstAttribute="trailingMargin" secondItem="dJP-b6-Ftm" secondAttribute="trailing" id="kia-ek-skG"/>
                                                                        <constraint firstItem="dJP-b6-Ftm" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="Oid-Rc-aH5" secondAttribute="topMargin" id="l5N-zS-cxF"/>
                                                                    </constraints>
                                                                </tableViewCellContentView>
                                                            </tableViewCell>
                                                        </prototypes>
                                                    </tableView>
                                                </subviews>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.75004076959999999" green="0.1040449888" blue="0.1206566915" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                <constraints>
                                                    <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="2v6-FK-vyt" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="20" id="Edy-hU-GY1"/>
                                                    <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="414" id="Isx-E5-2uJ"/>
                                                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="2v6-FK-vyt" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="30" id="OTY-td-pfO"/>
                                                    <constraint firstItem="2v6-FK-vyt" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="8PI-hl-lry" secondAttribute="leading" constant="30" id="T7h-dc-4QT"/>
                                                    <constraint firstItem="2v6-FK-vyt" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="8PI-hl-lry" secondAttribute="top" constant="20" id="dcV-5c-pkc"/>
                                                </constraints>
                                            </view>
                                        </subviews>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                        <constraints>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="8PI-hl-lry" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="20" id="018-wR-9xA"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="8PI-hl-lry" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="LQo-x0-VDn" secondAttribute="leading" constant="-20" id="FKC-nR-YRp"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="8PI-hl-lry" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="LQo-x0-VDn" secondAttribute="top" id="Gqv-OU-P2f"/>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="8PI-hl-lry" secondAttribute="bottom" id="KK5-wW-ozL"/>
                                        </constraints>
                                    </view>
                                </subviews>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="LQo-x0-VDn" secondAttribute="trailing" id="AE2-7E-9HG"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="LQo-x0-VDn" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="TPs-fa-Cha" secondAttribute="width" priority="250" id="Rte-o0-Glp"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="LQo-x0-VDn" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="TPs-fa-Cha" secondAttribute="top" id="aEU-v5-Cad"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="LQo-x0-VDn" secondAttribute="bottom" id="cO7-2E-0pT"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="LQo-x0-VDn" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="TPs-fa-Cha" secondAttribute="leading" id="m81-U4-SNF"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="LQo-x0-VDn" firstAttribute="height" secondItem="TPs-fa-Cha" secondAttribute="height" id="owm-Yu-tsT"/>
                                </constraints>
                            </scrollView>
                            <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" distribution="fillEqually" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="EJ1-7L-gD8">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="481" width="414" height="255"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="9zS-iV-m0P">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="414" height="127.66666666666667"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="0.66666666666666663" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
                                    </view>
                                    <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="lpS-nX-jsH">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="127.66666666666663" width="414" height="127.33333333333331"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" cocoaTouchSystemColor="viewFlipsideBackgroundColor"/>
                                    </view>
                                </subviews>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="255" id="oGk-Vz-GWg"/>
                                </constraints>
                            </stackView>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="1" green="1" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="EJ1-7L-gD8" firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" secondAttribute="bottom" id="EgJ-Wh-ZOP"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="EJ1-7L-gD8" secondAttribute="trailing" id="Srj-nB-74S"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="TPs-fa-Cha" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" secondAttribute="top" id="frI-np-m0B"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="EJ1-7L-gD8" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="TPs-fa-Cha" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="32" id="jfk-9F-7WW"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="TPs-fa-Cha" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" secondAttribute="leading" constant="20" id="pR9-do-d64"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="TPs-fa-Cha" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="-20" id="r3d-o9-LYw"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="EJ1-7L-gD8" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="6Tk-OE-BBY" secondAttribute="leading" id="vmi-E0-e52"/>
                        </constraints>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="6Tk-OE-BBY"/>
                    </view>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="label" destination="zrT-93-180" id="9YE-hX-UB7"/>
                    </connections>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="dkx-z0-nzr" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="139.13043478260872" y="132.06521739130434"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
</document>
```

Comment: You can use cells however you like, It is not related.